# Python Nested Loops questions python3.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-loops

I'm trying to write a nested loop that calculates (x+y)^2 for every value of y where the outer loop should print (x+y)^2. Here is my code so far:

```
x = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18]

y = [10,8.25,7.5,7,6.5,7,7.5,8.25,10]


for i in range(0 , len(x)):
# nested
    
    #for j in range(0, len(y)):
    for j in range(0, len(y)):
            
    
        print( (x[i] + y[j])**2)
```

My output keeps printing repeated values like so:

```
144
105.0625
90.25
81
72.25
81
90.25
105.0625
144
```

Comment: There is repeated values in `y` so you have repeated values in output.

Comment: Learn to iterate on values directly `for value in x:`

Comment: Try this - 
```for a, b in zip(x, y):
    print((a+b) ** 2)```

Comment: Both list have 9 values, do you expect 9 results or 81 ? each value of x with each each value of Y ?

Comment: your question is not clear you ask about (x+y)**2 and in your code your do for each x do (x+y)**2 this will result in len(x)*len(y) values please consider reformatting your question

Comment: I don't think you're using the phrase "outer loop" the way most people understand it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could try this:

NB - it works by zipping through two lists (same size) and do the math.  If the size is unequal, then you should try zip_longest with some other default number (for this shorter list).

```py
outs = []

for a, b in zip(x, y):
    outs.append(pow((a+b), 2))
```

#### Example 2:  one list is longer -

```py
x = [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18, 20]       # adding 20 as extra number

y = [10,8.25,7.5,7,6.5,7,7.5,8.25,10]

from itertools import zip_longest #(a, b, fillvalue=0)

outs = []

for a, b in zip_longest(x, y, fillvalue=0):
    outs.append(pow((a+b), 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using any library:

```
print([((x[i] if i < len(x) else 0) + (y[i] if i < len(y) else 0))**2 for i in range(max(len(x), len(y)))])
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[144, 150.0625, 182.25, 225, 272.25, 361, 462.25, 588.0625, 784]
```